# flutter mouse scrolling is not work in horizontal list

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, scroll

I'm making an horizontal ListView and I built some containers inside the ListView.

After making that, i wanted to test it on Web, So i scrolled it inside the ListView, but nothing happen.

I tried also `shift`+`wheel scroll` but it didn't worked either.

How can I test the listView on the flutter web? Thank you.

```
ListView(
  scrollDirection : Axis.horizontal,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: 160.0,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 160.0,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 160.0,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 160.0,
      color: Colors.yellow,
    ),
    Container(
      width: 160.0,
      color: Colors.orange,
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using debug mode (F12) in chrome.

You can use Toggle device toolbar (Ctrl +Shift+M), and by using this,

you can simulate the touch screen.

Thank you!